# GKPlayer loadPhotoForSize: withCompletionHandler: Sandbox Connection Error

Tags: sandbox, game-center

I am trying to get avatars for game center friends using the `loadPhotoForSize: withCompletionHandler:` but it keeps throwing `GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.`

Does this method not work on Sandbox Game Center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, it always gives this error if the player does not have a photo, but if I add a photo, the error goes away and it loads the photo correctly. I have only tested this in sandbox though, so I'm not sure if it works the same outside of sandbox.

Comment: I see - I guess I will just handle the error and hope that's all it is. It would have made more sense if it threw a 404 or something to let me know the real issue!